# openlayers3 : center and zoom extent to KML limits

Tags: zooming, kml, openlayers-3

Basic script to display a kml file on a tiled background with openlayer; I just switched from version 2 to 4.65, how can I zoom to the limits of the kml geometry ("vector" here) ?

```
        var wmsSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: "https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/geoserver/wms",
            params: {"LAYERS": "other:wwf-terrestrial-biomes", "TILED": true},
            serverType: "geoserver"
          });

        var wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            opacity: 0.15,
            visible: true,
            source: wmsSource
          });

        var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
            url: "kml_file.kml",
            format: new ol.format.KML()
        })
    });

        var map = new ol.Map({
            target: "map-canvas",
            layers: [wmsLayer, vector],
            controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
                new ol.control.ScaleLine({units: "metric"}), 
                new ol.control.FullScreen()
            ]),
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.transform([37.41, 8.82], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"),
                zoom: 3
            })
        });
```

I'd like to replace the `zoom: 3` and have the map centered and extended to the kml limits ?

Note : I used `kmllayer.events.register("loadend", kmllayer, function(evt){map.zoomToExtent(kmllayer.getDataExtent())});` with OpenLayers2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do what you want

```
var vectorSource = vector.getSource();
vectorSource.once('change', function(e){
    if (vectorSource.getState() === 'ready') {
        var extent = vectorSource.getExtent();
        map.getView().fit(extent);
    }
});
```

Solution mainly adapted from [How to get the extent of a GeoJSON vector source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32585318/how-to-get-the-extent-of-a-geojson-vector-source) (changed the variable name & removed second argument in `map.getView().fit` (required in the old time, now optional, not needed most of the time, like here)

Comment: Thanks, but I get a `TypeError: vector.getState is not a function` in the console, and no centering or zoom effect... I added your code after mine. Maybe I should use an older library than 4.65 or 5.0.0, I see some of the kml polygons are white while they should be colored and the full screen display is quite dark at least the background is nearly black, but maybe this is normal...

Comment: Changed: I was using the layer instead of the source. Try again :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I need to declare the kml source as a separate `new ol.source.Vector`variable, here `vectorSource`, and read `.getExtent()` from this variable, not from the `ol.layer.Vector` :

```
        var wmsSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: "https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/geoserver/wms",
            params: {"LAYERS": "other:wwf-terrestrial-biomes", "TILED": true},
            serverType: "geoserver"
          });

        var wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            opacity: 0.15,
            visible: true,
            source: wmsSource
          });

        var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            url: "'.$kml_f.'",
            format: new ol.format.KML()
        });

        var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: vectorSource
    });

        var map = new ol.Map({
            target: "map-canvas",
            layers: [wmsLayer, vector],
            controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
                new ol.control.ScaleLine({units: "metric"}), 
                new ol.control.FullScreen()
            ]),
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.transform([37.41, 8.82], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"),
                zoom: 4,
            })
        });

        vector.once("change", function(e){
                var extent = vectorSource.getExtent();
                map.getView().fit(extent);
        });
```

Thanks for your help !